# Trying to create a Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a loop

That the A1:AZ1 data should be copied across all sheets and pastespecial just values into new sheet.

```
Sub CombineData()
Dim I As Long
Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next

  Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Count"

  For I = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Set xRg = Sheet1.Range("A1:AZ1")

    If I > 2 Then
      Set xRg = Sheets(1).Cells(xRg.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
    End If

    Sheets(I).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ1").Copy
  Next
End Sub
```

FaneDuru Yes you are right and my comment limit has stoped

Comment: There are quite some bugs in your code what is Sheet1, you copy but don't paste, and even if you would, instead of copy/paste the best thing to do is to do `for Each rng in source_range destination_range.value = source_range.value Next`, something like that.

Comment: You've not explained the problem you're having or asked a question. Please [edit] your post to do both.

Comment: And get rid of `On Error Resume Next`, that's just hiding any potential error.

Comment: Please edit the code i do not know how to do it.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help you gain the knowledge so that you will be able to edit your own code. In order for us to help you in that way, it would help if you provide more details about what it is that you are trying to do and what problems you are encountering. I also second @BigBen 's suggestion to delete `On Error Resume Next`. All to often it functions as `On Error Hide Bug`. Step one in debugging is to delete that line. If you do so and get error messages, you could edit your question to include those messages.

Comment: Sir i do agree with your opinion to make it by my own, I have tried alot to modify it but could not,

I am trying to to copy the same range across multiple sheets and pasting-special values into new added sheet sequence wise

Comment: @ShoaibAli You didn't accept an answer to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639340/formula-addition-required after you received 3 answers, one from a member with a 17k rating. I'd be inclined to help, but you have to put in a bit more effort to try on your own, as well as express the proper grattitude (by clicking accept) when people DO help you.

Comment: PGSystemTester  I will close this task soon due to urgent reports could not check it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the next way, please. Now, it adds a new sheet and copy in it, on consecutive rows, the content of "A1:AZ1" range (as value) for all existing worksheets. Is this what you need?

```
Sub CopyRangeFromAllSheets()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, arr As Variant, lastEmptyR As Long
  
   Set sh = Sheets.aDD: sh.Name = "Count"
   
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> sh.Name Then
            arr = ws.Range("A1:AZ1").Value
            lastEmptyR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            sh.Range("A" & lastEmptyR & ":AZ" & lastEmptyR).Value = arr
        End If
   Next
End Sub
```

Edited by @Shoaib Ali not being able to post comments:

Yeah its working fine thanks and my comments limit is stopped

Comment: This is basically the answer I was going to give. Hopefully OP accepts it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but its not looking like what i want i have tried this code but its not working.

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: What do you mean by "its not working"? Do you receive an error? If you do not receive an error, does it do something else then your need? I did not include in the part adding the new sheet. You asked about the loop. I thought that adding a sheet is not a problem for you. What you needed to do is to select/activate the sheet from where you need the copy the range value and run the code. Should I understand that the range must be copied format included in all the sheets except the new one? You cannot be helped if you do not better describe what "its not working" means...

Comment: FaneDurr I have been using VBA to count by color, there is single color which values are appear in Range("A1:AZ1") when i run the given code then it erase the formula from all sheets which values are available in Range("A1:AZ1")

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: Did you understand my above questions? Can you answer them? What "pastespecial just values" from your question does mean? The code does what this words means. It pastes values... Please, try carefully reading my above questions and ask each of them. Of course, only if you need help in order to solve your problem...

Comment: @FaneDuru I also have tried to add the new sheet but could not if i could add the sheet by my own then do not request you to help, and the values that are being copied from Range("A1:AZ1") are formula i want just copied the value not formula not format.

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: I asked you twice: **Can you answer my above questions**? **I cannot help if I do not understand what you need**! Besides that, you said "when i run the given code then it erase the formula from all sheets which values are available in Range("A1:AZ1")". How else to look copying of a **range value** on all sheets? **Are you able to explain what do you need**, in fact? I try to be patient, but I am very busy and if you will also avoid answering my clarification questions I will only wish you succes with somebody else being more patient...

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: So, simplifying what you try saying: You need to copy **all existing sheets content of the range `"A1:AZ1"`** in a new added sheet. But, of course, on the next empty row, for each processed existing sheet. I mean, the new sheet will contain so many rows as the workbook has (except the newly created one). **Is that understanding correct**?

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: You do not say anything... I adapted the answer code to do as (I understood now) you need. Please, check it and confirm that it does as you need.

Comment: @Shoaib Ali: We here, when somebody spends some time and solve our question, tick the answer code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works... And a recommendation: Be more focused on the way you ask. It was very difficult to understand what you really need...